# Fallback to element.style media query?

Tags: html, css

Im wondering if it's possible to use the element.style at a certain media query.

Im working inside an application where a divs width is set by javascript on document load. Like this:

```
<ul style="width: 593.531px;" class="width-fix">

<style>
    .width-fix { 
        width:100%!important;
        min-width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

What I would like is that a certain break point just fallback to the element.style.

Should I use jquery to toggle this or can it be done with a media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it in the "reverse" way.

```
@media screen and (min-width: ###px)  {
  .width-fix { 
        width:100%!important;
        min-width:100%;
    }
}
```

This media query will only be active when the window is above a certain width. Meaning that when you fall under it, the !important rule will be removed and the inline css will kick in.

Comment: That's quite clever actually, wish I would have thought of that myself. I'll mark it as solved. Thank you.